# Cant delete a record from the form

Tags: c#

i am having two forms. one to stock entry and the other form which views the stocks in the grid-view. so now when i need to delete a record, i used to select the record from the grid-view and double click on the cell then the 'stock entry' will open with all the existing record.  then when i click on the 'delete button' its says its deleted successfully but nothing changed in the grid-view or the database.. the data still exists. please help me thank you .

link to my sql : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D5EpLZZ-2yVlOphaSBxOSC2vVLGabZ7W

my ID is set to auto-increment and the index type is set my stock is "Unique"

```
private void bunifuFlatButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 try
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Open();
        String DeleteQuery = "Delete from Stock_Jewelry where ID ='" + txt_ID + "';";
        SqlDataAdapter execute = new SqlDataAdapter(DeleteQuery, conn);
        execute.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("You've deleted successfully!", "Successful Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        conn.Close();
        this.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Did you re-queried and the rebind the DataSource? The grid will not magically know something changed in your database. Also your sql statement is open of sql injection. Look into SqlCommandParameter.

Comment: LITTLE BOBBY TABLES WISHES YOU A HAPPY DROP TABLE; YEAR.

Comment: To Delete record you don't need `SqlDataAdapter` you need `SqlCommand` only, the `SqlDataAdapter` is something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one because Id type is a int and txt_ID must be converts int;

```
String DeleteQuery = "Delete from Stock_Jewelry where ID =" + txt_ID;
```

Comment: The single quote in the SQL statement is interpreted as a string so you need to remove the single quote.

Comment: @jdweng ? String DeleteQuery = "Delete from Stock_Jewelry where ID =" + txt_ID;

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned your code is not secure for injection, this is better to use `SqlParameter` but about your problem:

Try this by `SqlDataAdapter` :

```
   try
   {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        connection.Open();
        adapter.DeleteCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
        adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = "Delete from Stock_Jewelry where ID =@id";
        adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txt_ID.Trim());
        adapter.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Row(s) deleted !! ");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

or simplest way like:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from Stock_Jewelry where ID =@id", con);
con.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txt_ID.Trim());
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

NOTE:

When Query ran in DB with no problem that means there is no problem with your code otherwise let us know what is exception in the other side there my be a problems with `txt_ID` such as space in it , or that entered Id does not exist in DB.